# Прошу проверить сочинение на пунктуацию, грамматику, смысловые связки и, конечно, на раскрытие темы

Tags: запятые, грамматика

**Тема**:

> Русский национальный характер в повести Н.С. Лескова «Очарованный странник»

**Сочинение**:

```
    В своем произведении «Очарованный странник» Лесков раскрыл душу 
русского человека через образ главного героя - Ивана Флягина. В нем 
автор отразил все главные черты русского национального характера, 
такие как стойкость, сострадание, способность к подвигу, умение не
сдаваться и многие другие. 

    Стоит уделить внимание портретной характеристике Флягина: «Это был 
человек высокого роста, с смуглым открытым лицом и густыми волнистыми 
волосами». Николай Семенович связывает его с Ильей Муромцем- героем 
былин, защищавшим родную землю от недугов. Это сравнение указывает на 
основные черты главного героя : мужество, доброта,  честь,
самопожертвование , отзывчивость. Однако все не так просто.
 
    Особенностью национального характера Лесков считает и 
неоднозначность натуры Флягина. Так, например, герой сгоряча может 
засечь насмерть (Иван Северьянович демонстрирует свою удаль, когда 
сечется с татарином). Но в то же 
время совершает подвиг и, рискуя собственной жизнью, спасает своих 
хозяев от неминуемой гибели.Вот в этом, по мнению автора, и 
проявляется широкая богатырская душа русского человека.


    Попав в плен к татарам, Иван Флягин грустит и скучает по Родине. 
Испытания плена одухотворяют строй чувств главного героя новой формой 
бескорыстной любви к России, которую ничего не может поколебать. И 
даже в пожилом возрасте, предчувствуя войну, Иван заявляет : «Мне за
народ очень помереть хочется». Эти слова символизируют главное 
свойство русского характера — готовность пострадать за других и 
умереть за Родину. 

    Иван Северьянович Флягина является поистине воплощением всего 
русского народа. В нем сочетаются такие качества, как смелось,
доброта , честность, верность, простодушность. Несмотря на трудности, 
которые ему пришлось преодолеть, он оставался искренним, верным 
своему сердцу, готовым помочь и никогда не сдавался. 
Такая красота души свойственна только русскому человеку, и только
русский человек может проявить ее так полно и широко!
```

Comment: @Зонтик (а также  Ivan Olshansky и Александр Стрелец) При правке (а также при ее утверждении), пожалуйста, обращайте внимание и на шапку. *Прошу проверить сочинение на пунктуацию, грамматику, смысловые связки и **кончено** на раскрытие темы!*

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова предложил правку опечатки. Правда пришлось поправить ещё кое-что, так как "правка должна быть не менее 6 символов"

Comment: "защищавшим родную землю от недугов" - от нед**р**угов, а не от недугов.

Comment: Очень красивое сочинение!

Comment: Согласен с тем, что "родина" у Лескова со строчной буквы, "Родина" с прописной - более позднее явление, к этому теоретически можно придраться. Про смысловые связки, не знаю точно как оценивают в школе, но для меня маловато формального перечисления добродетелей, лучше уменьшить их количество и сделать из них аргументацию: раз герой похож на Илью Муромца, то чем на примерах, а не на словах. То есть из фактического только "сгоряча насмерть сечется с татарином". Слишком уходите в перечисление штампов "совершает подвиг", "рискуя собственной жизнью" и тд., а о самом подвиге почти ничего.

Comment: Есть диссонанс "спасает хозяев" и "богатырская душа", он не хозяев спасал, а людей пожалел, пусть и не своей культуры, пусть и обошлись они с ним жестоко, когда физически его привязали к себе, зашив ему в пятки конский волос, чтобы Флягин не убежал. Но он не был их рабом ни разу. И когда тоска по родным местам и людям взяла верх - он убежал. В общем, мне не хватает в этом сочинении(или эссе) самой истории, много общих фраз, мало нарратива, то есть подробностей, которые именно вы заметили в этом произведении, не хватает вашего цепкого взгляда. А линия партии мне в целом ясна и знакома)

Answer (score 1):

Ну... Раз два голоса есть, то можно и проверить — на ошибки (отмечу их **жирным**).

Русский национальный характер в повести **Н. С.** Лескова «Очарованный странник»

В своем произведении «Очарованный странник» Лесков раскрыл душу русского человека через образ главного героя **—** Ивана Флягина. В нем автор отразил все главные черты русского национального характера, такие как стойкость, сострадание, способность к подвигу, умение не сдаваться и многие другие.

Стоит уделить внимание портретной характеристике Флягина: «Это был человек высокого роста, с смуглым открытым лицом и густыми волнистыми волосами». Николай Семенович **сравнивает** его с Ильей Муромцем **—** героем былин, защищавшим родную землю от **недругов**. **На это** сравнение **указывают** основные черты главного **героя:** мужество, доброта, честь, самопожертвование, отзывчивость. Однако все не так просто.

Особенностью национального характера Лесков считает и неоднозначность натуры Флягина. Так, например, герой сгоряча может засечь насмерть (Иван Северьянович демонстрирует свою удаль, когда сечется с татарином). Но в то же время совершает подвиг и, рискуя собственной жизнью, спасает своих хозяев от неминуемой гибели. **Вот** в этом, по мнению автора, и проявляется широкая богатырская душа русского человека.

Попав в плен к татарам, Иван Флягин грустит и скучает по **родине**. Испытания плена одухотворяют строй чувств главного героя новой формой бескорыстной любви к России, которую ничего не может поколебать. И даже в пожилом возрасте, предчувствуя войну, Иван **заявляет:** «Мне за народ очень помереть хочется». Эти слова символизируют **главные свойства** русского характера — готовность пострадать за других и умереть за **родину**.

Иван Северьянович **Флягин** **поистине** является воплощением всего русского народа. В нем сочетаются такие качества, как **смелость**, **доброта,** честность, верность, **простодушие**. Несмотря на трудности, которые ему пришлось преодолеть, он **остается** искренним, верным своему сердцу, готовым помочь и никогда не **сдается**. Такая красота души свойственна только русскому человеку, и только русский человек может проявить ее так полно и широко!

Н. С. Лесков — нужны пробелы между инициалами.
В первом абзаце, кажется, надо тоже использовать настоящее время.
Запятая и двоеточие пишутся без пробелов.
*Простодушность* — редкое слово (могут посчитать за ошибку). Да и хочется "разбавить" однородный ряд со множеством **-ть**.
[Родина](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0) — в этом тексте предлагаю писать со строчной буквы.